# LyX does not display definitions in the LaTeX preamble

Tags: macros, lyx, preamble

I have defined the following preamble in my LyX document:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\setR}{\mathbb{R}}
```

The first one is because the language I write in doesn't use indentations in the first line of a paragraph.

After compiling and displaying with pdflatex, I see the behaviour I expected, but in LyX itself, they are ignored. Is there a way to make LyX show them?

[image: view inside LyX]

[image: after pdflatex]

Comment: Hi, welcome. For the first: remove the `\setlength` from your preamble, and instead go to Document --> Settings --> Text layout, and set Indentation to Custom, 0pt.

Comment: In general, unless you use the LyX GUI to make settings, LyX will not display something. But as you noticed, it will be shown in the PDF output. This is partly why LyX does not claim to be WYSIWYG. LyX does not in general parse LaTeX that the user enters into ERT or custom preamble (an exception to this is if you import a TeX file via File > Import).

Comment: I'm getting an error message, "An error occured while running: tex2lyx -f "mymacros.tex" "mymacros.lyx" When trying to import (I chose import -> Latex (plain))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the paragraph indentation, don't use `\setlength` in the preamble, but instead go to Document --> Settings --> Text layout, and define the paragraph separation here:

[image: text layout settings in LyX]

It might be best to set it to some vertical space instead of just setting the indent to zero.

For `\setR`, if you define this using Insert --> Math --> Math macro instead, it will display as you'd like it to, while you can still input it with `\setR`.

[image: math macro]